# How to make pytest display a custom string representation for fixture parameters?

Tags: python, pytest

When using builtin types as fixture parameters, pytest prints out the value of the parameters in the test report. For example:

```
@fixture(params=['hello', 'world']
def data(request):
    return request.param

def test_something(data):
    pass
```

Running this with `py.test --verbose` will print something like:

```
test_example.py:7: test_something[hello]
PASSED
test_example.py:7: test_something[world]
PASSED
```

Note that the value of the parameter is printed in square brackets after the test name.

Now, when using an object of a user-defined class as parameter, like so:

```
class Param(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

@fixture(params=[Param('hello'), Param('world')]
def data(request):
    return request.param

def test_something(data):
    pass
```

pytest will simply enumerate the number of values (`p0`, `p1`, etc.):

```
test_example.py:7: test_something[p0]
PASSED
test_example.py:7: test_something[p1]
PASSED
```

This behavior does not change even when the user-defined class provides custom `__str__` and `__repr__` implementations. Is there any way to make pytest display something more useful than just `p0` here?

I am using pytest 2.5.2 on Python 2.7.6 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fixture decorator takes an `ids` parameter which can be used to override the automatic parameter name:

```
@fixture(params=[Param('hello'), Param('world')], ids=['hello', 'world'])
def data(request):
    return request.param
```

As shown it takes a list of names to use for the corresponding item in the params list.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the ids based on the params in a controlled way? For instance, I'd like to pass 3 "person" objects as params, but i'd like the IDs to be named against person.name, or even person['name']?

Comment: It is possible to pass a function to the `ids` parameter which will be called using the fixture value and can return a string or `None` for the automatic id.  This is documented in doc/en/fixture.txt in the repo but for some reason doesn't appear on the rendered version of the website currently, which is weird.

Comment: I can see it too, maybe an upcoming feature? I tried the example as-is in pytest 2.6.4 and got: _pytest\python.py:824: in parametrize -- if ids and len(ids) != len(argvalues): TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()